# Browser's Redirection

Tags: php, javascript, linux, iptables

I'm writing an internet access tool for a LAN that uses Linux + iptables to redirect to a login page everytime a user tries to access to any web page. That login page asks for user and password and if the authentication was successful, it removes the iptables rule so the subsequent requests goes to the originally intended webpage.

This is the situation:

1. If I go to http://www.abc.com, my default gw redirects me to 10.0.10.10/login.php
2. I successfully login.
3. If I try to go again to http://www.abc.com, the browser is automatically sending me back to  10.0.10.10, it's like some sort of caching.
4. If I try to enter to another page other than abc.com, it works as expected.

How can I tell the browser to remove the "remembered" rule of redirection?

Comment: <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> add this is your html head portion

Comment: Depends on the browser you use. I recommend FireFox with the web developers tool to disable cache for better developing websites https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Comment: It doesn't work with meta tags. That was my first attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

If you use these meta tags page wont be cached neither by a browser nor a proxy server:

```
<meta http-equiv=”expires” content="Wed, 22 Jul 1981 16:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to Hard Refresh cache.

Usually you can do that with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

or you change your rule to make the second redirection to same page but with some `#` fragment identifier

eg: if user enters `abc.com` and gets redirected on login if he tries to go again to `abc.com` and you see that he was logged in redirect him to `abc.com#1`

Comment: The problem is that I cannot see where the user intended to go because  the browser is directly going to the LAN IP instead of trying to connect to abc.com.

Comment: so what? you redirect from your lan ip .. capture and redirect from there, there will be 2 redirects.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing your point. If I do window.location = 'http://abc.com'; a redirection loop occurs. If I do the same in another browser, it works. Chrome is remembering for too long the redirection rule.

Comment: What I'm trying to say: If you get the user that he is already logged in you redirect him to the last referer + fragment: `window.location=document.referrer+'#myfragment';`

Comment: Since the redirection is to another IP other than the default's gw, the referrer is empty. The dft gw is 10.0.10.1, and its iptables is doing a DNAT to 10.0.10.10 :(.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that page/url from browser history using javascript that will do the thing you need.
and also when user clicks back button on browser he will not get back to the previous page where he/she was log in.